# How do I install the linux-libre kernel?

Tags: kernel, open-source

is it possible to install [linux-libre kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux-libre) on my ubuntu 64 bit version.

Advance thanks for all gnu free software developers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either add their repositories or download the deb from their mirrors

http://linux-libre.fsfla.org/pub/linux-libre/freesh/pool/main/l/linux-source-3.3.2-gnu/

Repository : `deb http://linux-libre.fsfla.org/pub/linux-libre/planet planet main`

Of course such a kernel is not supported here, and, honestly I would use one of the advised distros (Trisquel, BLAG , GNUSense).

http://trisquel.info/en/faq

http://www.blagblagblag.org/

http://www.gnewsense.org/

Comment: thanks dude.. unfortunately failed to fetch the repository on ubuntu 12.04 beta 2 64bits

Comment: Try another mirror http://jxself.org/linux-libre/ , other mirrors listed here http://www.fsfla.org/svnwiki/selibre/linux-libre/